# Program is too big to fit in memory Pyinstaller

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I have decided to try PyInstaller, and after compiling small executable I have tried to run it on windows 7 and got 'Program too big to fit in memory'

I have compiled in Ubuntu using:

python pyinstaller.py --onefile test.py
python pyinstaller.py --onefile test/test.spec

(I have tried without --onefile also)

Tiny python code which was compiled: http://pastebin.com/ZJbxEzuE

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: And if you compile on Windows?

Comment: I have not tried, it will be problematic to compile that from Windows, there could be any difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you have compiled your program on linux, you can run the resulting executable only on linux, and if you try to run it on windows you will get errors. In this case, it seams that the windows doesn't finde the end of the file, so it says that it is too big.

To run your program as an *.exe on windows you must compile it on windows (or run it directly from the *.py file).

Comment: Or run a VM with the OS the application was compiled for.

Comment: But it will be pain in the ass (installing libraries on VM before compiling every single project), are you sure that it's not possible to compile win executable from python?
thanks

Comment: PyInstaller says that it detects and bundles all the dependencies in to a single distributable package itself.  It also provides mechanisms for adjusting the search path and modules to grab if you need to.  What's the problem with compiling on a Windows machine in the first place though?